# What is the point of initializing extensions with the flask instance in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Following Miguel Grinberg's book Flask web development, I have to initialize alot of exetensions with the flask instance what is the point of doing this?

examples

```
app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself: when an object A needs the services of an object B to do it's job, how do you make B available to A ?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the source of each of those extensions to see what exactly they're doing.

In general, they are setting up configuration, setting up callbacks for before and after request events, and generally using information from the app to initialize.

If you don't pass the app (or later call `init_app`), then the extension can't finish initializing and could be unusable.